# Get input text from select bootstrap - select picker class

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, model-view-controller

I am trying to get the text the user inputs in the select picker to use it for an API call. #

This is my HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="medicineText" data-live-search="true">
      @foreach (var medicine in Model.MedicineSelectList)
      {
         <option value=@medicine.Value>@medicine.Text</option>
      }                       
</select>
```

The options when I first login the page are empty, when is start typing I am supposed to use the text I type in the select picker and call and API to filter the database with that text and fill in my options there and then.

**My issue is that I cannot find a way to get the input text the user inputs to filter.** For example if a user inputs 'abc' i need to get that text into a var an then passed on to the api's parameter as a string.

this is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true,
        showSubtext: true
    });

    $('#medicineText').change(function () {
        GetMedicineAccordingToText();
    });
});

function GetMedicineAccordingToText() {
    var text = document.getElementById('medicineText').value;

    if (text != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/NonPOYCPatient/GetMedicineAccordingToText',
            type: "POST",
            data: { medicineText: text },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {

        }).fail(function (response) {

        }).always(function () {
        });
    }
```

I have already tried .textContent, .val() using jQuery, .text, .val. Nothing seems to work... any help pleae?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example HTML code, here's one way to get the displayed text of the currently selected option:

function GetMedicineAccordingToText() {

```
 var medicineText= document.getElementById("medicineText");
 var text = medicineText.options[medicineText.selectedIndex].text;

if (text != null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/NonPOYCPatient/GetMedicineAccordingToText',
        type: "POST",
        data: { medicineText: text },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {

    }).fail(function (response) {

    }).always(function () {
    });
}
```

if its not working try

```
 $('#medicineText').select2('data')[0].text
```

Comment: Hey :) I think i didnt explain correctly. I dont want to get the selected option. I want to get the text the user is inputting in the select picker.

Comment: var data = $('#medicineText').select2('data')
alert(data[0].text);
alert(data[0].id);  try this

Comment: Didnt work :( Shouldnt be too hard to get the text I input in a search box right? :/